# 'method name' undeclared objC class

Tags: objective-c

I am attempting to simply call a method within the same class, e.g.

```
-(void) createRequest: (NSString*)urlFormatted {
    ...
 }

-(void) sendData {
   ...
   [createRequest request]; <- Error occurs here.
 }
```

> Error: 'createRequest undeclared'

Whether is was necessary or not, I also defined createRequest in associated header file, e.g.

```
-(void) createRequest: (NSString*)urlFormatted;
```

I'm very new to objective-c.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You are trying to call a static method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call the function like this
`[self createRequest:request];`

Comment: What you're actually doing in your code is calling the method `request` on an object called `createRequest` which is why you're getting the error since there is no `createRequest` object.

Answer (score 1):

You can call it with:

```
[self createRequest:request];
```

It helps to think in terms of objects sending each other messages. In this case, your object is sending itself a message to perform a request on an NSString.